# Injection between two groups / homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Suppose $\varphi:G_1\to G_2$ is a homomorphism and $H$ is the kernel of $\varphi$. We want to show that if $G_1$, $G_2$ are finite, then $G_1/H$ is finite.

My question is mainly about what can we say about the order of group $G'$ and $G''$ if there is a bijection/injection/surjection from $G'$ to $G''$? Is it analogous to the set theory?

For this specific question, my attempt is as follows:

since $G_1/H$ is the quotient group of $G_1$, $o(G_1/H)\mid o(G_1)$. Since there is a bijection between $G_1/H$ and $\varphi(G_1)$ and $\varphi(G_1)\subseteq G_2$, there is an injection from $\varphi(G_1/H)$ to $G_2$. $\textbf{Then I was not sure if I can assert that}$ $o(G_1/H)\mid o(G_2)$. If so, $o(G_1,H)$ is a common factor of $o(G_1)$ and $o(G_2)$ hence finite.

thank you

Comment: Every quotient of every finite group is finite. No extra hypothesis is needed.

Comment: So for this specific question, we don't need to know anything about $G_2$? (that also makes sense) @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Conversely, it is also enough that $G_2$ is finite, with no hypothesis on $G_1$. Are you sure that the question was not "If $G_1$ *or* $G_2$ are finite, then $G_1/H$ is finite" ?

Comment: Now I mainly want to ask what can we say about the relationship between $o(G_1/H)$ and $o(G_2)$. Can we say $o(G_1/H)\mid o(G_2)$ because there is an injection from $G_1/H\$ to $G_2$? @CaptainLama

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem says that $\varphi(G_1)\cong G_1/H$, so $G_1/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2$, so by Lagrange’s theorem $o(G_1/H)\mid o(G_2)$.